# ACLを保持したままコピーは出来ますか？

Tags: linux, filesystems

ACLを設定したファイルを[PinguyBuilder]でISOイメージ化して
USBブートさせたのですが、ACL情報が消えていました。
このACL情報を保持させたいのですが、何か方法はないでしょうか。

特定のユーザにだけ読み取り専用にしたくて、ACLを使っています。
ACL以外でも上述のことが出来れば方法があればご教示頂きたいです。

Answer (score 0, accepted):

PinguyBuilder では SquashFS というファイルシステムを使用して ISO イメージを作成しているようですが、SquashFS では ACL をサポートしていないようです。

https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/filesystems/squashfs.txt

> Squashfs filesystem features
>
> ACL support:  no

「特定のユーザーにだけ読み取り専用に」であれば、(ACL を使わない) 通常のアクセス権限の設定でも実現可能ではないでしょうか？